# Error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'EmployeeController'. Make sure controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Why I'm I getting this error on Employee Controller rest of them are working perfectly 
Here is my Employee Controller

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        #region Call service
        private readonly IEmployeeServices _employeeServices;
        public EmployeeController(IEmployeeServices employeeServices)
        {
            _employeeServices = employeeServices;
        }

        readonly IEmployeeServices employeeServices = new EmployeeServices();

        public EmployeeController():base()
        {
            _employeeServices = employeeServices;
        }
}
```

AND this is my perfectly Working Product Controller

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
    {
        #region Call service

        private readonly IProductServices _productServices;

        public ProductController(IProductServices productServices)
        {
            _productServices = productServices;
        }

        readonly IProductServices productServices = new ProductServices();

        public ProductController()
        {
            _productServices = productServices;
        }
}
```

Here is the stack trace

> An error has occurred.An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'EmployeeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.System.InvalidOperationException at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()An error has occurred.Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "TheWork.Controllers.EmployeeController", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:  Resolving TheWork.Controllers.EmployeeController,(none) Resolving parameter "employeeServices" of constructor TheWork.Controllers.EmployeeController(BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices employeeServices) Resolving BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices,(none) Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)&#xD; at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides)&#xD; at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides)&#xD; at Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)&#xD; at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)An error has occurred.The current type, BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?System.InvalidOperationException at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context) at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) at lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)

**Update**

Here is the Unity Configuration

```
   public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);

            RegisterTypes(container);
        }

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            ComponentLoader.LoadContainer(container, ".\\bin", "TheWork.dll");
            ComponentLoader.LoadContainer(container, ".\\bin", "BusinessServices.dll");
            ComponentLoader.LoadContainer(container, ".\\bin", "DataModel.dll");
        }
}
```

Comment: What does your unity configuration look like?

Comment: @ChrisBint Chris I added the Config class please see the update part of the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Buried in the stack trace is the root cause of the issue:

> **InvalidOperationException - The current type,**
>   **BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices, is an interface and cannot be**
>   **constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?** 
>   -----------------------------------------------  At the time of the exception, the container was:    Resolving
>   TheWork.Controllers.EmployeeController,(none)  Resolving parameter
>   "employeeServices" of constructor
>   TheWork.Controllers.EmployeeController(BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices
>   employeeServices)  Resolving BusinessServices.IEmployeeServices,(none)
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable1 resolverOverrides)

The issue is that the `EmployeeController` requires an instance of `IEmployeeServices` but Unity does not know what concrete type to instantiate. It looks like the implementation class is supposed to be registered by the call to `ComponentLoader.LoadContainer(container, ".\\bin", "BusinessServices.dll");` but for some reason it is not being registered.  It could be a bug in that code or perhaps the BusinessServices.dll is out of date and does not contain the `IEmployeeServices` definition.

It's hard to tell why `IEmployeeServices` is not registered without seeing all the code and runtime dependencies (because types are being dynamically loaded/registered).

Comment: Well thank you sir, you made me look into deeper and I'm sorry to all it was my mistake I didn't updated my `DependencyResolver` class. with 
`registerComponent.RegisterType<IEmployeeServices,EmployeeServices>();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :)

```
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IEmployeeServices >().To<EmployeeServices >().InRequestScope();
        }
```